# What is the meaning of "I made up my mind as a young kid "

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I met my father for the first time when I was 28 years old.
>   And I made up my mind as a young kid...
>   ...that when I had children...
>   ...my children were gonna know who their father was.
>   ([Source.](http://www.veryabc.cn/movie/uploads/script/thepursuitofhappyness.txt))

Comment: In general, please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) like where you found this example and any attempts you have made to answer your own question. Also, clearly indicate if there is a specific word or phrase that you don't understand. I suspect you are looking for [make up your mind](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+up+mind).

Comment: It's from pursuite of happiness movie when will Smith said that he met his father for the first time when he was 28 years old  and he made up his mind as a kid but what am not understand is the other sentence " I made up my mind as a young kid"

Comment: There seems to be some missing context. Is that the complete sentence? At the moment, it is not clear why he says "and". Also, the sentence makes me wonder, "To do what?"

Comment: I met my father for the first time when I was 28 years old. 

And I made up my mind as a young kid... 

...that when I had children... 

...my children were gonna know who their father was.  It's all sentence I guess

Comment: @Ohoud, could you tell us whether you know what the phrase "make up your mind" means on its own? As Max, I suspect that is where the trouble is, but it's hard to give you an answer that will help if we're not sure specifically what the problem is.

Comment: Am just not understand the meaning of sentence even in my own language  .so could you please explain the meaning of it ?

Answer (score 1):

> I met my father for the first time when I was 28 years old.
>   And I made up my mind as a young kid...
>   ...that when I had children...
>   ...my children were gonna know who their father was.

I made up my mind (I decided) as a young kid (being a young child or when I was a young child)...
*As* is a preposition meaning *being*

Comment: I would think the _as_ would be better paraphrased as _when I was_, rather than as _being_.